# NSString.rangeOfString returns unusual result with non-latin characters

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsstring, nsrange

I need to get the range of two words in a string, for example:

```
ยัฟิแก ไฟหก
```

(this is literally me typing PYABCD WASD) - it's a non-sensical test since I don't speak Thai.

```
//Find all the ranges of each word
var words:  [String]    = []
var ranges: [NSRange]   = []

//Convert to nsstring first because otherwise you get stuck with Ranges and Strings.
let nstext = backgroundTextField.stringValue as NSString //contains "ยัฟิแก ไฟหก"
words  = nstext.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
var nstextLessWordsWeHaveRangesFor = nstext //if you have two identical words this prevents just getting the first word's range

for word in words
        {

            let range:NSRange = nstextLessWordsWeHaveRangesFor.rangeOfString(word)
            Swift.print(range)
            ranges.append(range)

            //create a string the same length as word
            var fillerString:String = ""

            for i in 0..<word.characters.count{
            //for var i=0;i<word.characters.count;i += 1{
                Swift.print("i: \(i)")
               fillerString = fillerString.stringByAppendingString(" ")
            }

            //remove duplicate words / letters so that we get correct range each time. 
            if range.length <= nstextLessWordsWeHaveRangesFor.length
            {
                nstextLessWordsWeHaveRangesFor = nstextLessWordsWeHaveRangesFor.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: fillerString)
            }             
        }
```

outputs:

```
(0,6)
(5,4)
```

**Those ranges are overlapping.**

This causes problems down the road where I'm trying to use `NSLayoutManager.enumerateEnclosingRectsForGlyphRange` since the ranges are inconsistent.

How can I get the correct range (or in this specific case, non-overlapping ranges)?

Comment: There is only one print statement in your code, how do you get two output lines?

Comment: It's pseudo code really - trying to isolate the problem. In the app it cycles through words in the string.

Comment: A reproducible, self-contained example demonstrating the problem would be helpful.

Comment: on it - give me a mo.

Comment: You say that you don't know if this is valid Thai (and neither do I). Given that non-English languages often have combining marks, have you tried this with actual Thai? Maybe copy-paste something from a Thai national government website, that you can be reasonably sure will be grammatically correct.

Comment: @JoshCaswell that's a good idea, but shouldn't any given string return a valid range?

Comment: Yes, it would surprise me if that was actually the problem, but using known-good text would help to eliminate that variable.

Comment: You *modify* the nstextLessWordsWeHaveRangesFor variable inside the loop, that changes the character indices.

Comment: My confusion comes from how this works fine in non-latin character sets. How can I iterate through composed unicode characters instead of what appears to be the decomposed unicode character sets? `word.characters.count` is the expected length (4).

Comment: Swift characters and NSString characters count differently. Replacing `for i in 0..<word.characters.count` by  `for i in 0..<range.length` would be a simple fix.

Comment: @MartinR you literally made my day. Thank you. I think this should be the correct answer.

Comment: @MartinR I need to know your lunch break schedule so I might have a snowball's chance in grabbing some SO karma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift `String` characters describe "extended grapheme clusters", and `NSString`
uses UTF-16 code points, therefore the length of a string differs
depending on which representation you use.

For example, the first character `"ยั"` is actually the combination
of `"ย"` (U+0E22) with the diacritical mark `" ั"` (U+0E31).
That counts as one `String` character, but as two `NSString` characters.
As a consequence, indices change when you replace the word with
spaces.

The simplest solution is to stick to one, either `String` or `NSString`
(if possible). Since you are working with `NSString`, changing

```
 for i in 0..<word.characters.count {
```

to

```
for i in 0..<range.length {
```

should solve the problem. The creation of the filler string
can be simplified to

```
//create a string the same length as word
let fillerString = String(count: range.length, repeatedValue: Character(" "))
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing `nstextLessWordsWeHaveRangesFor` solves the issue (at the bottom starting with `range.length <= nstextLessWordsWeHaveRangesFor.length`). The modification of that variable is changing the range and giving unexpected output. Here is the result when the duplicate word removal is removed:

```
var words: [String] = []

let nstext = "ยัฟิแก ไฟหก" as NSString
words = nstext.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

for word in words {
    let range = nstext.rangeOfString(word)
    print(range)
}
```

Output is: `(0,6)` and `(7,4)`